# Need to return an array of struct in c from jni to java (as Object array)

Tags: java, c++, object, java-native-interface

I have to return a array of structure values from c++ (jni) to java. I have the c++ struture as follows

```
MyCStructure
{

byte *Data;
int dataLength;
int width;
int height;
}mycstr;
```

And i have my java structure as

```
public class MyJavaStructure
{
    public byte[] Data;
    public int dataLength;
    public int width;
    public int height;
}
```

And My **JavaMainClass.java** is

```
   MyJavaStructure[] mystr =  MyJavaStructure[4]; 
public native int Process();
public LSImage getValues()
{
     return this.mystr ;
}
public void setValues(MyJavaStructure bDetails)
{
     this.mystr = bDetails; 
}
```

I tried to pass Object array (MyJavaStructure) directly from JNI using GetMethodId of setValues.

My JNI code is

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_TestJNI_Process(JNIEnv *jEnv, jobject jObj)
{

    MyCStructure* mycstr = new MyCStructure[4];

    iRet = Process(&mycstr);

    jclass jClass = jEnv->GetObjectClass(jObj);
    jmethodID constructor;


    jmethodID jObjectID = jEnv->GetMethodID (jLegendClass, "setValues", "(LMyCStructure;)V");
    if (jObjectID == NULL)
    {
        throwJavaException(jEnv, "Unable to find the method setValues");
        return NULL;
    }
    jEnv->CallObjectMethod(jObj, jObjectID, (jobject *) mycstr);

    printf ("After setting the output data value\n");

    jEnv->DeleteLocalRef(jClass);

    return iRet;
}
```

The value returned in mycstr contains 4 array of structure (MyCStructure) values and i tried to assign in a MyJavaStructure class object but it returned null.

Am i doing right or is there i have to change anything ?

Answer (score 0):

```
jEnv->CallObjectMethod(jObj, jObjectID, (jobject *) mycstr);
```

You obviously can't do that. `mycstr` is not a `jobject`, neither pointer to `jobject`. `jobject` itself is already a pointer to opaque structure, which shouldn't be of your interest to decouple you from dependency on particular JNI implementation.

Native code in C can understand Java classes and object thanks to set of JNI functions callable from C. There is nothing reciprocal on Java side to understand native objects. **So the answer is no, you are not doing it right.**

If you want a structure (a simple class) synchronized between Java and native, pass the class instance as jobject to the native call, and use `GetFieldID` followed by (for example) `Get/SetIntField`.

Comment: if it was a single structure i can use Get/Set Fields. I need to pass array of structure. The 'mycstr' contains structure with 4 values.

Comment: Your java method `setValues(MyJavaStructure bDetails)` takes a single instance, not an array, so it won't work anyway. So then you need to wrap your array in a class and have methods `setDataLength(indexInArray,value)` and similar, and call those over JNI. There is no bypass how to hand C objects over to Java directly, really.